# Different constructor signature for derived class

Tags: oop, typescript

Is it break oop principles (ex, Liskov principle), if constructor signature for derived class is not the same as base class?

```
class Base {
  protected x: number;  
  protected y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  private text: string; 

  constructor(text: string, x: number, y: number) {
    super(x, y);
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, because Liskov principle talks about "contravariance of method arguments and return types in the subtype". When you do something like this:

```
foo(bar:Base){
  //do stuff
}
```

this method expects an **instance** of `Base` class, not a constructor so the contravariance of methods does not apply to this case.

It would break this principle if you did something like this, because a `Base` instance could not be replaced by an `Extended` one :

```js
class Base{

  foo():string{
    return "";
  }

  bar(arg:string){}

}

class Extended extends Base{

  foo():number{
    return 1;
  }

  bar(arg:boolean){}

}
```

But this is not allowed by the typescript compiler.